# How can I log with params with a thrown?

Tags: java, logging

With `java.util.logging.Logger`, how can I log with params and a thrown?

```
final Object[] params;
final Throwable thrown;
```

I can't find any method with `log(Level, String, Object[], Throwable)`.

Should I use `log(Level, String.format(...), Throwable)` or `log(Level, Throwable, () -> String.format(...))`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to put both `String` and `Object[]` to [java.util.logging.Logger](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/logging/Logger.html#log(java.util.logging.Level,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Throwable)).

I would convert `String[]` to `String` and use:

```
public void log(Level level,
                String msg,
                Throwable thrown)
```

---

Also you can create your own `log` method that points to `java.util.logging.Logger.log`, something like:

```
public void log(Level level,
                    String msg,
                    Object[] obj,
                    Throwable thrown)
{
   //StringBuilder buff = ...
   // some string manipulation with 'msg' and 'obj'
   // ...
   log(level, buff.toString(), thrown);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In general it looks like JUL is moving towards `log(Level, Throwable, () -> String.format(msg, params))`.  However, this doesn't use the [log record parameters array](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/logging/LogRecord.html#setParameters-java.lang.Object:A-) which has some utility with filters.

Another option is to create a helper method to [construct the log record](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/logging/LogRecord.html) and let the caller [log it](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/logging/Logger.html#log-java.util.logging.LogRecord-):

```
public class ThrownWithParams {

    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("test");

    public static final void main(String[] args) {
        logger.log(of(logger, Level.SEVERE, new Exception("Fake"),
                "Test {0}, {1}", "FOO", "BAR"));
    }

    private static LogRecord of(Logger l, Level v, Throwable t, String m, Object... p) {
        //Let the caller invoke get/setSourceClassName or get/setSourceMethodName.
        LogRecord r = new LogRecord(v, m);
        r.setLoggerName(l.getName());
        r.setResourceBundleName(l.getResourceBundleName());
        r.setResourceBundle(l.getResourceBundle());
        r.setParameters(p);
        r.setThrown(t);
        return r;
    }
}
```

This is ideal because the caller logs the record which means that the inferred source method and source class names will be correct.