# Varargs in java.util.logging java 8

Tags: java, java.util.logging

We are using java.util.logging

```
void log(Level level, Throwable thrown, Supplier<String> msgSupplier)
```

and a few more convenience methods like

```
logp(Level level, String sourceClass, String sourceMethod,
                                                String msg, Object params[])
```

But no varargs method. How come? Does this seem like a future enhancement or is there any good reason not to have something like :

```
    public void log( Level level, Throwable t, String msg, Object... params) {
        // throw new RuntimeException("No yet impl");
        if (!isLoggable(level)) {
            return;
        }
        LogRecord lr = new LogRecord(level, msg);
        lr.setParameters(params);
        if (t != null) {
            lr.setThrown(t);
        }
        doLog(lr);
    }
```

I created helper :

```
    public static void log(Logger logger, Level level, Throwable t, String msg, Object... params) {
        // throw new RuntimeException("No yet impl");
        if (!logger.isLoggable(level)) {
            return;
        }
        LogRecord lr = new LogRecord(level, msg);
        lr.setParameters(params);
        if (t != null) {
            lr.setThrown(t);
        }
        logger.log(lr);
    }
```

would loved to have called doLog instead of log in the last line, but doLog is a private helper! Not sure why, as there is no way for me to set the bundle etc - wish it was

public  void doLog(LogRecord lr) instead of private.

Anyway, for us to do the same things the following method does so that we can use our own varargs method?

```
// resource bundle and then call "void log(LogRecord)".
private void doLog(LogRecord lr) {
    lr.setLoggerName(name);
    final LoggerBundle lb = getEffectiveLoggerBundle();
    final ResourceBundle  bundle = lb.userBundle;
    final String ebname = lb.resourceBundleName;
    if (ebname != null && bundle != null) {
        lr.setResourceBundleName(ebname);
        lr.setResourceBundle(bundle);
    }
    log(lr);
}
```

Comment: This is opinion-based. `java.util.logging` was introduced in Java 1.4. Why hasn't it taken advantages of all of the features of later Java versions? Nobody knows except the package authors. Probably because they have better things to do.

Comment: Old API.  Sun and Oracle saw no need for updating.  You may want to consider using slf4j to abstract the implementation away and get varargs.

Comment: I second that. SLF4J is the industry standard these days. It has a better API and is fully compatible with JUL.

Comment: Its not just opinion based, in a system with a lot of txns and db ops, not creating threads unless the logging level needs it, is a big saving. Having less anonymous methods is less over head on the heap too. Can test memory for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But no varargs method. How come? Does this seem like a future enhancement...

There are multiple requests for [Use varargs in java.util.logging.Logger](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-5001993) on the OpenJDK site over the years.  The API wasn't really [maintained after JDK 5](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/logging/index.html).  Logging was updated in JDK 8 for [Lambda Expressions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/language/lambda_api_jdk8.html) but the logging guide wasn't updated for best practices just a few examples in the [java.util.logging.Logger](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/logging/Logger.html).

> I created helper `public static void log(Logger logger, Level level, Throwable t, String msg, Object... params)`

You might want to use the version in [How can I log with params with a thrown?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41208319/how-can-i-log-with-params-with-a-thrown/41226434#41226434) as it will retain the correct class and method name because the caller is still responsible for publishing the log record.

> is there any good reason not to have something like `log(Level level, Throwable t, String msg, Object... params)`

It is probably safe addition. [Oracle ran a survey](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/lambda-dev/2012-December/007395.html) and it is clear they would prefer you to use a lambda or method reference with one of the log methods that takes a `Supplier<String>` and lean on the [java.util.Formatter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html) providing the supporting for var-args.

```
} catch (IllegalArgumentException iae) {
    logger.log(Level.SEVERE, iae, () -> String.format("%1$s is too many.", count)); 
}
```

Sugary sweet lambda syntax over vegetables!

Comment: Yes I tested a log when the log level is on and off, giving a function is less performant. Wish we had varargs. We plan to move this to log4j2 API soon, anyway the backend is log4j2

Comment: Also, the supplier versions do any formatting on the logging thread before constructing a LogRecord, whereas the parameters versions just dump the message and parameters into the LogRecord, so a handler could do it on another thread (or [defer it entirely](https://blapid.github.io/cpp/2017/10/31/llcpp-a-quest-for-faster-logging-part-2.html)).